# Browser Tab Animation

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

[image]

I wanted tto ask - for a couple of sites - fb and gmail come to mind - they will show an slight cloud/white like animation that passes over the Tab.

I assume this action is controlled by Jquery/javascript.

Does anyone have any information on how to implement this.

Note: I can explain this better if needed.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The favicon can be animated using HTML5 `<canvas>`, exporting the canvas as an image. See [here](http://remysharp.com/2010/08/24/dynamic-favicons/) for a very interesting article about how to do it.